# grid css 2 column and second column with 2 rows

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, css-grid

I am new to the grid css and I want to achieve somenthing like this[image]

I'm stuck with the first one and can't fix the proper ordering of the 2nd column

Here's what I did

```
.image-wrapper {
        display: grid;
        gap: 1.5rem;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);

        .image-container:nth-child(1) {
            grid-column-start: 1;
        }

        .image-container:nth-child(2) {
            grid-column-start: 2;
            grid-row: 2;
        }

        .image-container:nth-child(3) {
            grid-column-start: 2;
            grid-row: 3;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To create similarly styled layouts, you can try and use the `grid-area` concept. Check out this [amazing, interactive guide](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/interactive-guide-to-grid/) by Josh Comeau.

Using the code from the example on the website (resize the window to see the mobile layout), you can create a mobile-first approach like the following snippet:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.child {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: #eee;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 5fr;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 'sidebar header' 'sidebar main';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    child
  </div>
  <div>
    else
  </div>
  <div>
    something else
  </div>
</div>
```

**On a final note**, make sure to search on Stackoverflow before posting your question, this and [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401674/how-to-create-a-css-grid-layout-box-that-spans-2-columns-and-2-rows) have already been answered.